# java.lang.string cannot be cast to java.util.Vector

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm unable to figure this out. My code is throwing this error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
>    .WebService.parseJourney

```
    public static ArrayList<Journey> parseJourney(Object response) {
      ArrayList<Journey> rs = new ArrayList<Journey>();
      try {
        if (response == null) {
            return rs;
        }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Vector<Object> result = (Vector<Object>) response;
        if (result.size() < 4) {
            return rs;
        }
```

Am sure have used generics with no issues in past.

Wow - that was quick.
The call to parseJourney :

```
    Vector<EntryValue> values = new Vector<EntryValue>();
    EntryValue value = new EntryValue();

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_ENTRY, METHOD_NAME_ENTRY);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("values");
    pi.setValue(values);
    pi.setType(MyArrayList.class);

    request.addProperty(pi);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL_ENTRY);
      try {
          aht.call(SOAP_ACTION_ENTRY, envelope);
          Object response = envelope.getResponse();
          resultEntry = parseJourney(response);
          return response.toString();
          } 
      catch (Exception e) {
    ERROR_EXCEPTION = 1;
    return e.toString();
     }
    }
```

Comment: `response` holds a `string`, apparently... can you show the call to `parseJourney`?

Comment: Obviously you want to cast a `String` to a `Vector`: `Vector<Object> result = (Vector<Object>) response;`. `response` is a `String` (that's the compiler saying

Comment: Show us how `parseJourney` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseJourney() receives a String and you are trying to cast it to Vector without testing it

```
if(response instanceof Vector)
{
   Vector<Object> result = (Vector<Object>) response;
   //...
}
```

And don't put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, it's generally a bad practice

Comment: point taken about warnings. Am still getting to grips with java, no NSMuttableArray to utilize, will get testing and 'tick'  answers, many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The Object that is being passed into `parseJourney()` is a String, not a Vector. If you want more information than that, you'll need to include whatever code calls `parseJourney()`.